# Silverlight Datagrid readonly to select column without focusing cell

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I'm trying to use grid for lookup of data (selecting record to edit).
Basically, it's read-only grid, when user double-clicks row I take value and pass it back.

So, it works good, but this cell focus just drives me crazy. How do I get rid of it so it selects full row?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change style of DataGridCell and delete that focus rectangle like below

```
<Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell">
                    <Grid Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CurrentStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Regular" />
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Current">
                                    <!--<Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>-->
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Duration="0" To="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!--<Rectangle Name="FocusVisual" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#66FFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" />-->

                        <ContentPresenter
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />

                        <Rectangle x:Name="InvalidVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="False" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FFDC000C" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0"/>

                        <Rectangle Name="RightGridLine" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```